# Geckodriver in jar file

Tags: java, selenium, jar, geckodriver

I have a (maybe) very simple question. Is it possible to put a geckodriver inside of a jar file, so that I can use it with selenium, or would I need to install it on every device I want to run this program on? Or is there an installation of the geckodriver in Mozilla Firefox?

Thanks in advance. If there really is no other option, I might have to make the jar file install the geckodriver.

Comment: you need it to exist on any machine you want to use it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`web driver manager`](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager)

> WebDriverManager resolves the driver binaries for the browsers Chrome, Firefox, Opera, PhantomJS, Microsoft Edge, and Internet Explorer. For that, it provides several drivers managers for these browsers.

so for example if you want to bring the `gecko driver` wherever you are just use it like that :

```
WebDriverManager.getInstance(DriverManagerType.FIREFOX).forceCache().setup();

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```